# Preserve &nbsp in title

Tags: 7

I'm currently working on a French website. French formatting requires a space before question marks. For some of my titles, this results in the question mark appearing on a line by itself.

> Why does it do this
>
> ?

It looks like trash. How can I preserve the `&nbsp;` in the title to have the question mark on the same line?

Answer (score 1):

You can use these two modules:

[Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title)

> Do as follow:
>   In content type field management, use replace button to turn title core into a text field; set up the field to be in a full html text format;
>   In content type display management, show new title field;
>   In file node.tpl do not print the core $title;

[HTML Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/html_title)

> It let you insert some sort of BBcode into the title. I've never used it and I don't know if there is a BBtag for